# How to parse an array of json object using jq

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I need to parse a Json file which have a lot of arrays.

**This is the json source:**

```
{
"iabVersion": "IAB_V2",
"categories": [{
    "categories": [{
        "categories": [{
            "id": "1.1.1",
            "name": "Commercial Trucks"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.2",
            "name": "Convertible"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.3",
            "name": "Coupe"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.4",
            "name": "Crossover"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.5",
            "name": "Hatchback"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.6",
            "name": "Microcar"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.7",
            "name": "Minivan"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.8",
            "name": "Off-Road Vehicles"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.9",
            "name": "Pickup Trucks"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.10",
            "name": "Sedan"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.11",
            "name": "Station Wagon"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.12",
            "name": "SUV"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.13",
            "name": "Van"
        }],
        "id": "1.1",
        "name": "Auto Body Styles"
    }
  }
}
```

**This is the json requred:**

```
{
"id": "1.1.1",
"name": "Commercial Trucks"
}
{
"id": "1.1.2",
"name": "Convertible"
}
```

**How can I parse it via jq?**

10x:)

Comment: your output has only 2 objects, do you really need only the first 2 items?

Comment: @user9763887 - please clarify the functional requirements.

Comment: I need the whole objects, the 2 object are just example to how the output should look like. even if I run :   cat /home/ubuntu/pcn/iab/source/dmp-data-source.json | jq '.categories[0].categories[0].categories[],.categories[0].categories[0].categories[]' > /home/ubuntu/pcn/iab/result/dmp-data-result1.json
It did not catch the "id"="1.1"

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the JSON input has been corrected, the following jq filter seems to meet the requirements, such as they are:

```
.categories[].categories[].categories[]
```

This produces a stream of JSON objects, beginning:

```
{
  "id": "1.1.1",
  "name": "Commercial Trucks"
}
{
  "id": "1.1.2",
  "name": "Convertible"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you fix the malformed JSON data by closing arrays like this:

```
          ...
          "id": "1.1",
          "name": "Auto Body Styles"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

you can use the following `jq` script:

```
$ jq '.categories[0].categories[0].categories[0],.categories[0].categories[0].categories[1]' file
{
  "id": "1.1.1",
  "name": "Commercial Trucks"
}
{
  "id": "1.1.2",
  "name": "Convertible"
}
```

The jq statement selects the first and second array element in these nested arrays.

Comment: But the Json as required need to fill in all the id+name (not just in the example)...

Comment: If I understand you well,  you need  `jq '.categories[0].categories[0].categories[]' file`. If not, please update your question with the exact requirement.

Comment: I need the whole objects, the 2 object are just example to how the output should look like. even if I run :   cat /home/ubuntu/pcn/iab/source/dmp-data-source.json | jq '.categories[0].categories[0].categories[],.categories[0].categories[0].categories[]' > /home/ubuntu/pcn/iab/result/dmp-data-result1.json
It did not catch the "id"="1.1"